# What's with Steve Job and crabs reference in Aiura opening song?

Tags: aiura

In Aiura opening there's a lot Steve Job and crabs reference

[image: Steve Job phone crab][image: Steve Job think crabing]

There are still lot more than this. And the whole opening song is all about crab, and sometimes Steve Jobs make some appearance like two pictures above randomly. The anime it self has nothing to do with crab. What's with that? Why Steve Jobs? Why crabs?

Comment: I remember this being asked at some point in time. When I'm at a computer I'll see if it was culled somehow...

Comment: So yeah, this was indeed asked several years ago - at https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3749/whats-the-deal-with-all-the-crabs-in-the-aiura-op - and was deleted due to [a DMCA takedown notice](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4050/my-post-was-removed-due-to-dmca-takedown-notice-what-can-i-do).

Comment: @Makoto I didn't know it's here when I posted this. If it's impossible to reopen the question maybe posted the answer here yourself since most of us can't see deleted question

Answer (score 3):

Transcluding [bcy's answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/5659/) from the previous instance of this question, under the assumption that the answer wasn't what triggered the DMCA complaint:

> It may actually be a layered joke on the title referring to a Japanese battle. First "Aiura" is pronounced the same way as "iUra", like an apple product, hence Steve Jobs in the OP. On the other hand the Tale of Heike says that the spirits of samurai who fell during the battle of Dan-no-Ura are carried by Heike crabs, and that's why their backs sort of look like a human face. That explains why there are crabs everywhere in the OP, which happen to also be linked with Steve Jobs since he died from cancer.
>   Thanks 4chan for this explanation : https://desuarchive.org/a/thread/87335497/#87336503 https://desuarchive.org/a/thread/87872828/#87880558

[Note: I updated the 4chan archive links to point to an archive that is still alive. archive.foolz.us went down quite some time ago.]